# removing root page from navigation stack?

Tags: xamarin.forms

my pages are
`Page 2` (root page and using it as a splash screen progress bar) -> `Page1`
now what i want is when Page 2 finishes doing some logic it goes to page 1 and make Page1 my root page so that when user click back button it exits the application

i dont want when user press back button to navigate to `Page 2` (root page and using it as a splash screen progress bar)

how can i implent that and here is my Code
`App.xaml.cs`

```
 public partial class App : Application
{
    public App()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        MainPage = new NavigationPage(new Page2());
    }
```

`Page2.cs`

```
 public partial class Page2 : ContentPage 
{
    
    
    public Page2()
    {
        InitializeComponent(); 
           .....some logic code ....

       Navigation.PushAsync(new NavigationPage(new Page1()));
    }
```

and in my `page1.cs`

```
 public partial class Page1 : ContentPage
{
      public Page1()
      {
        InitializeComponent();
        App.Current.MainPage = new NavigationPage(new Page1());
        Navigation.RemovePage(new Page2());

    }
```

it appears black Screen , IDK how to solve this issue , thx :)

Comment: `Page1's` constructor does `App.Current.MainPage = new NavigationPage(new Page1());` which will cause infinite recursion.  And if you are assigning `MainPage` directly, there is really no reason to directly modify the Navigation stack.  Finally, `Navigation.RemovePage(new Page2());` does not do anything useful.  You need to remove the existing instance that is ALREADY on the stack, not a new instance that is NOT on the stack.

Comment: i need to modify the navigation stack so that when i press back button it wont navigate back to `Page2` all i want to do is just to demonstrate `Page2` only once per application running then when it navigates to `page1` to removes the root page from my stack so when i press back button to exits application , and frankly i dont know how accomplish that

Comment: instead of navigating from Page2 --> Page1, just assign MainPage = Page1 when Page2 is complete.

Comment: `Page2` is a content page not a splash screen, u mean smth like that `public Page2(){ InitializeComponent(); App.Current.MainPage = new NavigationPage(new Page1());`

Comment: if you want to make X the new root page and eliminate any prior navigation history, do it by assigning MainPage.

Comment: i used smth like that `public Page2(){InitializeComponent();App.Current.MainPage =new NavigationPage(new Page1());Navigation.PopToRootAsync();`still wont pop to the new root page `page1`

Comment: why are you doing this in the page constructor?!?!?!  What is the possible utility of that?  And there is NO need to call PopToRootAsync if you have just assigned a new MainPage.

Comment: i have to do this in the page constructor so as soon as some logic code is done ( which i will Bind to a progressbar)  it will navigate automatically to `page1` and i want to remove the root `Page2` so that when i press back while i am on `Page1` it wont navigate back to my mimic splash screen `Page2`

Comment: if you do it in Page2's constructor then Page2 will never display

Comment: so how can i make `page 2` navigate automatically to `Page1` after it does some business Logic which btw i will code it in the page Constructor :(

Comment: WHEN that business logic completes, THEN reassign MainPage.  And do NOT do it in the constructor.  Do it in OnAppearing, so that Page2 will display itself first

Comment: i hope u can bear up with me :/ here is what i did ` protected override void OnAppearing()
        {
            base.OnAppearing();
            //MyLogic
            App.Current.MainPage = new NavigationPage(new Page1());
        } the problem is while doing my logic it displays black screen then it goes to `page1` and it works fine

Comment: I have no idea what your "logic" consists of, but I assume that you're doing it wrong.

Comment: here is how i worked this around , to make page appear i had to use `async` like this `protected override async void OnAppearing(){base.OnAppearing();await Task.Delay(10000); App.Current.MainPage = new NavigationPage(new Page1());` now i have to put my logic into smth that can be awaited

        }

Comment: my logic code is a bunch of string to my azure storage and some  table query execution any idea how can i wrap them into an `awaitable` method to use them instead of `await task.Delay()` ?

Comment: use a proper task, or async/await.  If you need more help, ask a new question with specific details

Answer (score 0):

> Page 2 finishes doing some logic it goes to page 1 and make Page1 my
> root page

in Page2, whenever your code "finishes"

```
App.Current.MainPage = new NavigationPage(new Page1());
```